# C++ Sets - Union, Difference, Intersect - Causing vector erase iterator error (Outside of range)

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, set

Okay, I have been banging head on the wall at this. Sometimes when the code is run, I run into a error "Expression: vector erase iterator outside range". It is an intermittent problem. Assume it has something to do with the numbers being randomly generated into the vector. To get the error the code may have to be run more than once.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

template <class T> class set
{
public:
    void add(T newElement);
    void remove(set<T> newElement, int pos);
friend set<T> operator-(set<T> set1, const set<T> set2){
    set<T> result;
    result = set1;
    for (int i = 0; i < set1.setVec.size(); i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < set2.setVec.size(); j++){
            if (set1.setVec[i] == set2.setVec[j]){
                result.remove(set1, i);
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}
friend set<T> operator&(const set<T>& set1, const set<T> set2){
    set<T> result;
    for (int i = 0; i < set1.setVec.size(); i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < set2.setVec.size(); j++){
            if (set1.setVec[i] == set2.setVec[j]){
                result.add(set1.setVec[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
friend set<T> operator|(const set<T>& set1, const set<T> set2){
    set<T> result;
    result = set1;
    for (int i = 0; i < set2.setVec.size(); i++){
        result.add(set2.setVec[i]);
    }
    return result;
}
friend ostream& operator<< (ostream &output, const set<T> setOut){
    output << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < setOut.setVec.size(); i++){

        output << setOut.setVec[i] << endl;
    }
    return output;
}
private:
    vector<T> setVec;
};
template <class T> 
void set<T>::add(T newElement){
    setVec.push_back(newElement);
}
template <class T>
void set<T>::remove(set<T> newElement, int pos){
    vector<T>::iterator it;
    it = setVec.begin();
    this->setVec.erase(it+3);
}
int main(){

    srand(time(NULL));

    cout << "=====INTEGERS=====" << endl;
    set<int> s;
    s.add(rand() % 10 + 1);
    s.add(rand() % 10 + 1);
    s.add(rand() % 10 + 1);
    s.add(rand() % 10 + 1);
    s.add(rand() % 10 + 1);
    s.add(rand() % 10 + 1);
    cout << "Set 1: " << s << endl;

    set<int> s2;
    s2.add(rand() % 10 + 1);
    s2.add(rand() % 10 + 1);
    s2.add(rand() % 10 + 1);
    s2.add(rand() % 10 + 1);
    s2.add(rand() % 10 + 1);
    s2.add(rand() % 10 + 1);
    cout << "Set 2: " << s2 << endl;

    set<int> s3;    
    s3 = s | s2;
    cout << "Set 1 Union Set 2: " << s3 << endl;
    s3 = s & s2;
    cout << "Set 1 Intersect Set 2: " << s3 << endl;
    s3 = s - s2;
    cout << "Set 1 Difference Set 2: " << s3 << endl;

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Basically, I am just trying to recreate set notations in c++ for a templated class. I have been on this for about 6 hours. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I believe this `this->setVec.erase(it+3);` should be `this->setVec.erase(it+pos);`... Looks like a typo :)

Comment: Changed it, but I don't think that was the entire problem. Thing I have been at it too long. lol.

Comment: Dont change it in your question !!! This makes your question (and answers) almost completely useless to future readers

Comment: Well honestly it is questionable if this question will help any future reader ;) But sarcasm aside, you should not fix what you were asking for in your own question! If you found a fix you can post it as answer and if there is already an answer with a fix you can accept this one.

Comment: Sorry! Didn't think about that. Thanks.

Comment: @tobi303 Yeah, sorry I mean to post it with the pos in the correct position. The error still comes up with the pos corrected though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `remove` looks wrong:

```
template <class T>
void set<T>::remove(set<T> newElement, int pos){
    vector<T>::iterator it;
    it = setVec.begin();
    this->setVec.erase(it+3); // <--------------- maybe (it+pos) ??
}
```

And when erasing elements you have to take care that the size changes while you remove elements, i.e. :

```
friend set<T> operator-(set<T> set1, const set<T> set2){
    set<T> result;
    result = set1;                           // here result.size == set1.size
    for (int i = 0; i < set1.setVec.size(); i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < set2.setVec.size(); j++){
            if (set1.setVec[i] == set2.setVec[j]){
                result.remove(set1, i);     // now result.size is smaller
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

it is probably easier to use iterators. Something like:

```
friend set<T> operator-(set<T> set1, const set<T> set2){
    set<T> result;
    result = set1;
    for (auto result::iterator it = result.first();it != result.end();/*empty*/){
        if (hasToBeRemoved(it)){
            result.remove();
        } else {
            ++it;
        }
    }
```

you can do the same also without iterators but you have to consider, that if you earase element at position 3, then the next element is actually at position 3 (and not 4).

Comment: ps: the error message was actually quite clear, maybe you just need a break ;)

Comment: Yeah I might! Lol. I was trying something, but for some reason it is giving me the same error even with the correction.